# Which surfaces have nontrivial actions of the circle (by homeomorphisms)?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, transformation-groups

Let $S$ be a $2$-dimensional manifold such that the circle $S^1$ acts nontrivially on $S$ by homeomorphisms.  What can we conclude about $S$?

If $S$ is a compact oriented surface on which $S^1$ acts nontrivially by diffeomorphisms, then I know how to prove that $S$ is either the sphere or a torus.  Probably this can be easily extended to non-oriented surfaces or to surfaces of finite type (i.e. compact surfaces minus a finite set of points).  But I don't know how to do this for either infinite-type surfaces, or for actions by homeomorphisms (and this seems fundamental since without some kind of differentiability I don't know how to show that the action preserves a Riemannian metric, which is the first step in the proof for diffeomorphisms).

I don't even know how to deal with actions by homeomorphisms on closed oriented surfaces, and this is what I am primarily interested in.  But I am interested in the more general question as well.

Comment: I believe every topological circle action in 2 dimensions is smoothable, though I don't know a reference, so this comment is probably not useful to you. The key step is to verify the action is locally linear near every orbit. I suspect that the answer is that $S$ is one of $$S^2, D^2, S^1 \times I, T^2, K, M,$$ or the result of deleting some of their boundary components. Further, as long as the action is effective, it should be isomorphic to the standard action on the above.

Comment: This may be overkill, but for orientable surfaces of genus at least two it follows from Thurstons classification of surface homeomorphisms, Consider the action of a non-trivial element of finite order, then it gives a periodic homeomorphism homotopic to the identity. By Thurstons result a periodic homeomorphism is isotopic to a hyperbolic isometry, hence acts non-trivially on $\pi_1$. My guess is it was known much earlier, and can probably be deduced from Bredon's book.

Comment: There is a paper of Conner and Raymond "Lie group actions on aspherical manifolds" from which e.g. follows that hyperbolic surfaces cannot admit such actions, and the action is homotopically injective in a suitable sense. See also https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303261.

Comment: If you have a nontrivial continuous action of $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$ on a non-orientable connected manifold $M$, then you get a nontrivial continuous action of $\mathbf{R}/2\mathbf{Z}$ on its orientation (2-fold) covering. So it remains to check individually the few cases where the orientation covering admits an action (for closed surfaces, this just means $P^2$ and the Klein bottle and it's OK. The Möbius strip, with or without its boundary, is OK too; maybe that's it).

Answer (score 5):

The relevant reference is a paper of Borel:

**Theorem(Borel):** Let $M$ be compact hyperbolic manifold. Then every continuous circle action on $M$ is trivial.

A. Borel: On periodic maps of certain K(π, 1), In: Œuvres: Collected Papers III,
57-60. Springer, 1983.

Comment: I think this too is overkill. All you need for this result is (a) circle actions on surfaces are locally linear near orbits, and (b) the Lefschetz fixed point theorem. The theorem follows immediately because each fixed point has positive Lefschetz number (thanks to our knowledge of the local structure) and thus $\chi(S) \ge 0$. If you can prove (c) that an $S^1$ action on a noncompact surface has an exhaustion by $S^1$-invariant compact submanifolds, then you get that $\chi(S) \ge 0$ in the noncompact case too. Still, Borel's paper is nice.

Comment: You are right. i think (a) might be related to the following https://math.unice.fr/~emiliton/cerclesursurfaces.pdf